# quantum affine $gl_2$

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

There are many sources of the relations and Hopf algebra structure of quantum affine $sl_2$ as a deformed enveloping algebra. However, for an application to integrable systems I need to look at quantum affine $gl_2$, not $sl_2$. Also it would be really good to see how this fits into the Drinfeld realisation with the $h_r$ and $x^\pm_r$ for $r\in\mathbb{Z}$. I would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean the following presentation in terms of generators and relations:

[image]

The excerpt is from:

- Evaluation modules for quantum toroidal ${\mathfrak{gl}}_n$ algebras, [arXiv:1709.01592v4 [math.QA]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.01592v4), p.3

I think the OP might also find some interest at:

- On Drinfeld realization of quantum affine algebras, Naihuan Jing, [arXiv:q-alg/9610035](https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9610035)
- [MULTIPLICATON FORMULAS AND CANONICAL BASES FOR QUANTUM AFFINE ${\mathfrak{gl}}_n$](https://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/%7Ejied/papers/duzhao3_submitted1.pdf)

You can also see (both Jimbo's and Drinfeld's presentation of the quantum affine $sl_2$) at:

- [Relation between Yangian $Y(sl_2)$ and quantum affine algebra $U_q(\widehat{sl_2})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1491838/195021)

Comment: Many thanks for that! Is there any particular reason why the degree operator is left out? I assume that it could be put back in...